# Dynamic components from service response without entryComponents in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I'm using Angular 8 and trying to build a system that allows our clients to select which components they want to load from an array of components. We have about 10 components that will have 3 versions each for them to choose from. I want to use dynamically generated components using the componentFactoryResolver, so that I can build "component A" for client 1, "component B" for client 2, and based on the response from a service load one of those components, effectively allowing them to create their own versions of our site (from given "templates").

The problem is, all of these components have to go into entryComponents to be pre-compiled. Probably half of these components were lazy loaded to begin with, and I don't want to pre-compile 3 versions for each component. I'd ideally want to compile them on the fly based on the response from the service (telling me which one to load).

Are there any solutions to get around this entryComponents mayhem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntryComponents is no longer needed and was deprecated for Angular 9, so a good fix would be to upgrade to Angular 9.

Comment: Wow...am I lucky or what! Before Angular 9 I wouldn't have been able to solve this problem, but now it's been solved for me. Thanks!